# How to get total rows count of grid view while data source is domain data source with query parameters and paging is also enabled?

Tags: c#

Code as below. I'm able to get the `IQueryable` type of collection, but I also want to get the total rows count.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="dsBiz"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="false"
                DataKeyNames="PinCodeId" PageSize="5" OnDataBound="GV_DataBound">
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:DomainDataSource ID="dds" runat="server" QueryName="GetPinCodeInfoList" DomainServiceTypeName="postoffice.Controller.Biz">
                <QueryParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlState" Name="stateId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDistrict" Name="district" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlTaluka" Name="taluk" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                </QueryParameters>
            </asp:DomainDataSource>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to get the total rows count?

Comment: I am trying to get that count on row data bound event .

Comment: You should POST that code too!

Comment: Did you try `dds.Data.Count()`?

Comment: DomainData Source does not have such property and I also tried to get the data source of grid view in Data Bound Event of Grid View but it always shows null .And data property which you are saying is available in ria controls .

Comment: I am able to get approximate count using page size and page count but I want to get the exact count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124782/discussion-between-kothari-and-sachin).

Answer (score 1):

For that I added count value in HttpContext before the method" GetPinCodeInfoList" returns the value and then used where it is required.

```
                ` //Added Count in the context
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("Count", count);
            //update that value wherever required
            HttpContext.Current.Items["Count"] = count;
            //Access that value anywhere in same context
            String countString = HttpContext.Current.Items["Count"].ToString();`
```